# How to write unit test for sleuth?

Tags: spring-boot, junit5, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am using sleuth in my springboot application. Now I want to write unit tests to make sure that traceId is generated for the requests. Any advice or code reference on this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a controller method that returns the traceId.  To obtain the traceId, inject `Tracer` and get the traceId from the current span's context.

An `@WebMvcTest` won't include the necessary auto-configuration for this, so I guess you'd actually have to start the server, send the request and inspect the result.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. :)

If your component uses a `Tracer` to create the spans, you can just inject a mock (e.g.: with Mockito) and do you verifications on the mock.

If you want to test Sleuth's instrumentation, you need to start at least the context so it is not strictly a unit test anymore, you can see the usage of the `ApplicationContextRunner` in Sleuth tests.

You can also check the logs, return the tracing data in the response or set-up wiremock (instead of Zipkin) and test if Sleuth sends the spans to it.

Also, if you are using the latest snapshot (or wait a little till it will be released): we have now a new actuator endpoint that returns the most recent spans in Zipkin format: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/pull/1964